# Calculator Loop in Python

Tags: python, calculator

Need to add a loop to my calculator by giving the user an option to restart the calculator by putting the code in a while loop with the condition that the input from user should be, 'y' or 'Y'.

```
def add(x, y):
   return x + y

def subtract(x, y):
   return x - y

def multiply(x, y):
   return x * y

def divide(x, y):
   return x / y

print("Select operation.")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")

choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):")

num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

if choice == '1':
   print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))

elif choice == '2':
   print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))

elif choice == '3':
   print(num1,"*",num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2))

elif choice == '4':
   print(num1,"/",num2,"=", divide(num1,num2))
else:
   print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: How about you try something?

Comment: Try to do a [while](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) loop. Make the loop continue if the user inputs 'y' or 'Y'. Return here if you can't make it work, but not without trying.

Comment: You *do* know how to make a loop? Have you tried reading a book or tutorial on Python?

Comment: BTW, have a look at the `operator` module.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I'm new to Python. I'm 16 and learning online. I've tried looping buy I keep getting small errors. Kept trying and finally ended up here. I did try though!

Answer (score 2):

Just add somethings to Alex's post

```
cont = "y"
while cont.lower() == "y":
    print("Select operation\n1.Add\n2.Subtract\n3.Multiply\n4.Divide")

    choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):")

    num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

    if choice == '1':
       print(num1,"+",num2,"=", (num1 + num2))

    elif choice == '2':
       print(num1,"-",num2,"=", (num1 - num2))

    elif choice == '3':
       print(num1,"*",num2,"=", (num1 * num2))

    elif choice == '4':
       print(num1,"/",num2,"=", (num1 / num2))
    else:
       print("Invalid input")
    cont = input("Continue?y/n:")
    if cont == "n":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `while` loop example :

**Changed**

```
again = "y"
while again:
    # ...
    #enter your code here
    # ...
    a = input("do you want to do again (y/Y): ")
    if a not in ("y","Y"):
        a=""
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't really see what the problem is, you can just use another input statement and check the value in the while loop condition...

```
cont = "y"
while cont == "y" or cont == "Y":
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Add")
    print("2.Subtract")
    print("3.Multiply")
    print("4.Divide")

    choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):")

    num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

    if choice == '1':
       print(num1,"+",num2,"=", (num1 + num2))

    elif choice == '2':
       print(num1,"-",num2,"=", (num1 - num2))

    elif choice == '3':
       print(num1,"*",num2,"=", (num1 * num2))

    elif choice == '4':
       print(num1,"/",num2,"=", (num1 / num2))
    else:
       print("Invalid input")
    cont = raw_input("Continue?y/n:")
```

Comment: `while cont.lower() == "y"`

Comment: Gives me this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ratik/Desktop/Python/CALC2.py", line 27, in <module>
    cont = raw_input("Continue?y/n:")
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: Are you using python 2.7 or python 3.x?

Comment: raw_input has been removed in python 3.x, input should do the trick as well.

Comment: I'm Using 3.x  I'll try just using Input

Comment: Just Tried it. When enter y is loops. And when I enter Y it loops as well

Comment: When You enter y it should loop, when user enters Y it should say goodbye.

Comment: Kinda Got it to work just need to add the GoodBye part

Comment: @KokaRatik Can you explain the sense behind this? Why don't you take another letter for "goodbye"?

Comment: Working on an assignment! I've done pretty much everything else. Just want the program stop when User enters "Y: and the program says Goodbye.

Comment: I mean... the sense behind this odd user questioning. Normally you would use y/Y for "yes" and n/N for "no". Why do you want it to depend on upper and lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply modify your code like this

```
def continue():
    resp = input("Continue ? Y/N ")
    if resp == "n" or resp == "N":
        return False
    return True
while True:
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Add")
    print("2.Subtract")
    print("3.Multiply")
    print("4.Divide")

    choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):")

    num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

    if choice == '1':
       print(num1,"+",num2,"=", (num1 + num2))

    elif choice == '2':
       print(num1,"-",num2,"=", (num1 - num2))

    elif choice == '3':
       print(num1,"*",num2,"=", (num1 * num2))

    elif choice == '4':
       print(num1,"/",num2,"=", (num1 / num2))

    else:
       print("Invalid input")
    if not continue() :
       break
```

you can change the continue function as you like

Comment: You don't need the variavle `run`. Just loop `while True:` and use `if not continueU(): break` in the loop.

Comment: The `continue` function should be defined outside of the loop and you will have to remove the conversion to `int` in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
    while True:
        b = int(input('first num: '))
        c = input('operator: ')
        d = int(input('second num: '))
        if c == '+':
            print(b + d)
        elif c == '-':
            print(b - d)
        elif c == '*':
            print(b * d)
        elif c == '/':
            print(b / d)
        q = input('do you want to continue?: ')
        if q == 'y':
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another while loop example

```
menu ="""
 0. chose 0 to quit
 1. chose 1 to add
 2. chose 2 to sub
 3. chose 3 to multi
 4. chose 4 to div

"""
chose= None


while(chose != 0):
    print(menu)
    num1 =int(input('first num is: '))
    num2 =int(input('second num is: '))
    chose= int(input("plz enter your chose: "))
    if(chose == 1):

        print(num1, " + ",num2," = ",num1+num2)
    elif(chose == 2):
        print(num1, " - ",num2," = ",num1+num2)
    elif(chose == 3):
        print(num1, " * ",num2," = ",num1+num2)
    elif(chose == 4):
        if(num2 == 0):
            print("You can not divide by zero")
        else:
            print(num1, " / ",num2," = ",num1+num2)
    else:
        print('plz enter a correct option')
```

Comment: Use some Code Sample editing to organize your answer.